# Words/phrases meaning in/out of one's direct line-of-sight?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

When I am not looking at something, I say that it is in my peripheral vision. When I am looking at something, I say that I am looking right at it - i.e. it is in my line-of-sight. Are there words or phrases that describe this other than the ones I gave? My examples seem a bit wordy to me.

Comment: Clarifying the context that 'peripheral' would be used in would result in answers/words more specifically appropriate!

Comment: Can you give an example sentence?  Something like "I didn't see the car because it was <some word>"?

Answer (score 4):

You may use the expressions ***"[out of/from the corner of your eye](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/out-of-from-the-corner-of-your-eye)"***: 
​

> - If you see something out of/from the corner of your eye, you see it but not clearly because it happens to the side of you:
>
>   - *I saw something move out of the corner of my eye.*

(Cambridge Dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

In visual astronomy, there is the term "averted vision".

See the article [How to master the art of averted vision](http://www.skyatnightmagazine.com/feature/how-guide/how-master-art-averted-vision)

Answer (score 0):

There are a few words that would fit here, although your context should be clarified for a more specific answer. All definitions come from Merriam Webster dictionary.

*Tangential* - Of, relating to, or along a target.

*Subsidiary* - Less important then, or supplementary to.

*Marginal* - Of, relating to, or situated at the edge or margin of something.